# Menu Item visible but shouldn't

Tags: permissions, joomla3.0

I have created a menu item on my site that links to a form.
This menu item has a special access level. Everyone can see it but guests and one group called 'Founders' which has 'Public' as parent.

Now if a user is not logged in, the item doesn't show (which is correct). Once he logs in, he can see the menu item. If he clicks on the link and fills out the form that opens, the user gets automatically added to the 'Founders' group. He is now a member of the groups 'Registered' and 'Founders'.

The menu item however is still visible, because the group 'Registered' has access to it. What do I have to do, so that a user cannot see this menu anymore after becoming a member of 'Founders'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be impossible. The user cannot be in both groups. If the 'Registered' group is taken away then everything works as intended.
Only other thing that needs to be done is, that this 'Founders' group is checked in the Access Level of 'Registered' under 'User Groups Having Viewing Access'